# Enabling/Installing Curl Extension (OSX Server/PHP 5.3.3/Apache 2.2)

Tags: php, macos, apache

I've been having some trouble getting CURL working with PHP on a server I inherited.

So far I have enabled the extension in my php.ini by uncommenting the `extension=php_curl.dll` line, and restarting apache.

However, I now receive the following error when starting PHP:

`PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/php_curl.dll`

The php_curl.dll file doesn't exist in the aforementioned directory, and I can't find anywhere  legitimate to download it from(doesn't seem to be included in PHP, or Curl).

---

**UPDATE**
Following the steps provided in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523504/php-warning-unable-to-load-dynamic-library), I was able to compile a new php_curl.so file and install it to the extensions directory.

Cudos go to [Francois Deschenes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577300/francois-deschenes)!!

To compile a curl.so (php_curl.dll) module from scratch:

1. Download and extract a new copy of your version of PHP.
2. Open a terminal window and go to the curl directory (Type `cd php-5.3.3/ext/curl/`).
3. Type `phpize`.
4. Type `./configure`.
5. Type `make`.
6. Type `sudo make install`.
7. Uncomment `extension=curl.so` in your php.ini.

You should also make sure the extension is commented out before you start the processes, otherwise you may receive an error about the module already existing.

Comment: If I look in the directory all the other extension files have the extension `.so`. 

Still, there is no php_curl.so file either.

Comment: you may want to post this on Server Fault

Comment: Stumbled across a solution. I've updated my post near the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the steps provided in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523504/php-warning-unable-to-load-dynamic-library), I was able to compile a new php_curl.so file and install it to the extensions directory.

Cudos go to [Francois Deschenes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577300/francois-deschenes)!!

To compile a curl.so (php_curl.dll) module from scratch:

1. Download and extract a new copy of your version of PHP.
2. Open a terminal window and go to the curl directory (Type `cd php-5.3.3/ext/curl/`).
3. Type `phpize`.
4. Type `./configure`.
5. Type `make`.
6. Type `sudo make install`.
7. Uncomment `extension=curl.so` in your php.ini.

You should also make sure the extension is commented out before you start the processes, otherwise you may receive an error about the module already existing.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use

```
sudo port install php5-curl
```

(on php54: php54-curl)?

Answer (score 2):

Download the 'port' using the following URL and install it:

http://www.macports.org/install.php

There are different versions and you can select one installation pack for your Mac Version.

After installed, open a terminal and type the following command to install directly,

```
$ sudo port install php5-curl
```

Otherwise
- Login to port terminal by just typing

```
$ sudo port
```

and type

```
> install php5-curl
```

It will get few minutes to install all the dependancies and finally you will see the following message

```
--->  No broken files found.
```