# Curl_function and array in the url

Tags: php

i've been answered in my question here :

[File_get_contents($url): failed to open stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368057/file-get-contentsurl-failed-to-open-stream/25370859)

, and since i work with that function which was great for performance , now i'm facing a strange problem which is when i have an array in  my url , the function stops of working , is there any solution ?

here is an example of the url :

```
http://website.com/file.php?a=save&param1=90&param2=1330&paramS[399]=on&paramT[5]=Mme&Names[2]=Tantan&types[3]=Martine
```

**updated :**
the function you gived me :

```
function curl_function($uri) {
    $parsed_url = parse_url($uri);
    //Create fixed url
    $fixed_url = $parsed_url['scheme'] . '://' . $parsed_url['host'] . $parsed_url['path'];
    //If exists query
    if (isset($parsed_url['query'])) {
        $output = array();
        $result = array();
        //Extract querystring
        parse_str($parsed_url['query'], $output);
        //Encode values in querystring
        forEach ($output as $k => $v) {
            $result[] = $k . '=' . rawurlencode($v);
        }
        //Append encoded querystring
        $fixed_url .= '?' . implode('&', $result);
    }
    //Get result in page
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 30; //set to zero for no timeout
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fixed_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
    $errornum = curl_errno($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $status = (int) $info['http_code'];
    if ($errornum !== 0) {
        echo 'Error: ', curl_error($ch);
        $file_contents = NULL;
    } else if ($status !== 200) {
        echo 'http_error: ', $status;
        $file_contents = NULL;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $file_contents;
}
```

it doesn't work with the url i wroth above , but when i do a simple file_get_contents($url) it works fine ...

**updated :**
The error i get :

```
( ! ) Warning: rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\pretty.php on line 24
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi user3911183, which function exactly does not work? Could you explain how your code should work (edit the question please)?

Comment: i did update my question.

Comment: Your link to the previous section suggests you're using curl. Please provide verbose debugging information as outlined in [an answer to Php - Debugging Curl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14436877/367456).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento: I guess he means the function you suggested him here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25370859/367456 - btw. what is it about the query string recomposition? why so much work for standard URLs like in this case?

Comment: But displays an error? "curl_exec" returns something?

Comment: yeah , i've update my question with the error.

Comment: @user3911183: The problem is you arrays multiple levels deep in your query string, so you need a recursive functions in order to use `implode` and `rawurlencode` the string. But that just begs the question of why disassemble and reassemble it in the first place.

Comment: how can i do that without affecting the functionality of the function for the other urls which are simple ?

Comment: @hakre, thanks great link, but the problem is not with the "curl".

Comment: @user3911183: Use two functions: One is to fix the URI, one is to do the curl request. Then only fix those URLs which needs fixing. Then all correct URls use your transport function. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with the `CURL` is that the "for loop" was getting a `array` and the "rawurlencode" does not work with "arrays", the best in case urls with "array" is to use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Example:

```
<?php

/**
 * rebuild URI by re-encoding query parameters
 */
function rebuild_uri($uri) 
{
    $parsed_url = parse_url($uri);
    $buffer     = $parsed_url['scheme'] . '://' . $parsed_url['host'] . $parsed_url['path'];

    if (isset($parsed_url['query'])) {
        parse_str($parsed_url['query'], $output);    
        $query = http_build_query($output, null, null, PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
        $buffer .= '?' . $query;
    }

    return $buffer;
}

/**
 * Get result in page
 */
function curl_function($uri) 
{    
    $ch = curl_init($uri);
    $timeout = 30; //set to zero for no timeout
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
    $errornum      = curl_errno($ch);
    $info          = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $status        = (int) $info['http_code'];
    if ($errornum !== 0) {
        echo 'Error: ', curl_error($ch);
        $file_contents = NULL;
    } else if ($status !== 200) {
        echo 'http_code: ', $status;
        $file_contents = NULL;
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    return $file_contents;
}

$uri = rebuild_uri('http://localhost/?a[1]=1á&b[c]=1 as dasd&test[]=2&test[]=');
echo curl_function($uri);
```