# Enable Curl on custom built php7

Tags: php, ubuntu

I compiled & installed php7 as below

```
./configure --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --enable-calendar --enable-exif --enable-dba --enable-ftp --with-gettext --enable-mbstring --with-mcrypt --with-mhash --enable-pcntl --with-pspell --enable-shmop --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-sysvmsg --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-wddx --with-zlib --enable-zip --with-readline  --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-zts --enable-pthreads --prefix=/usr --with-config-file-path=/etc --prefix=/usr/local/php7



# sudo make
# sudo make install
```

The problem is that, I need to rebuilt & install php7 **--with-curl** . How do I remove installed complied version completely to get executed from shell.

Comment: just use ./configure , make, make install again, Any special reason not to use a precompiled version of php?

Comment: did that, but executing php on shell, does not update anything at all

Comment: I'm not using websever. It's executed on shell. But I did reboot the system

Comment: I checked that with php -m and can't use precompiled because I need to use pthreads

Comment: What is the output of `php -i`?

Comment: @Chris that's too big

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241477/enabling-installing-curl-extension-osx-server-php-5-3-3-apache-2-2

Comment: @PedroLobito that does not work in my case. Is that possible to uninstall compiled php completely

Comment: @PedroLobito got this error after enabling in php.ini 

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: @Chris here's output of php -i http://codepaste.net/i1mvas

Comment: @RishabhGoyal It looks like you are trying to enable the Windows version of Curl on Linux. Try enabling `php_curl.so` rather than `php_curl.dll`.

Comment: You're using ubuntu, php_curl.dll is for windows. Why not simply install phpt via apt-get ?! http://askubuntu.com/a/705893/442702

Comment: @Chris thanks a lot we nailed it. I made duplicate file of php_curl.so from curl.so. And changed right php.ini. If you want to you may post answer and I'll accept that. Thanks again :)

Comment: @RishabhGoyal I'm glad I could help. I've posted an answer.

Comment: @PedroLobito thanks for your valuable time

Comment: You're very welcome @RishabhGoyal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of the output of `php -i`, it appears you are trying to load `php_curl.dll` which is the Windows version of Curl. Try loading `php_curl.so` instead.